# Neo4j Count Distinct Nodes returning more Nodes than the Total

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to count all the nodes in my graph where a specific relation does not happen.

I have 1816 nodes in my graph.

When I run the following query:

```
MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2)
WHERE NOT (n1)-[:wikipedia]->(n2)
RETURN count(distinct n1)
```

Or:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
WHERE NOT type(r)='wikipedia'
RETURN count(distinct n)
```

I get: 2202

Above even the number of nodes!

What is wrong?

Neo4j version 3.5.1

Comment: are you sure that you have 1816 nodes in your graph?

Comment: run this to count the number of nodes:  MATCH (n) RETURN count(*) then tell us if it returns 1816

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've tested it before and checked it now once again.

Comment: In second query, you are not declaring second node. try (n1)-[r]->(n2) in second query

Comment: Try replacing  `count(distinct n)`  With `size(collect (n1))`

Comment: @Raj, it incresed to 7462.

Comment: @Umesh Patil, this doesn't change the response.

Comment: You may want to run a [consistency check](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/consistency-checker/) on your offline db. It could be possible you have an inconsistency in your count store. If so, you can delete the `neostore.counts.db.*` files and the counts will be rebuilt.

Comment: Ok, some inconsistencies were found. How can i solve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you found inconsistencies with the consistency check means your Neo4j database is corrupted. The first thing you should do is take it offline and [back it up](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup/performing/) before attempting any restore/repair.

Once you have your backup, you could try deleting the "neostore.counts.db.*" files to force Neo4j to rebuild them, but I would not recommend it since by definition of Neo4j being in an invalid state, it is impossible to know how much actual damage there is (corrupt nodes and what not). I would recommend either restoring from an older backup (if you have any) or using a restore tool like [store-utils](https://github.com/jexp/store-utils) to rebuild the whole database, throwing out any invalid nodes/relationships.

Comment: I have the following problem: [WARNING] The requested profile "enterprise" could not be activated because it does not exist. org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/tiago_duque/Área de Trabalho/Dissertação/Neo4jBackups/store-util-3.3.4). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Comment: @TiagoDuque Are you sure you pulled the correct branch? You should only be getting the message if you pulled one of the older branches (before the common-enterprise db difference was introduced)

Comment: Ok, used the Store-utils to rebuild the database using the database itself (i made a hard copy - had to deal with permissions afterwards, but no probl). It took me a while to figure out the steps needed to install and use store-utils (you dont download the zip, you have to get it entirely by cloning the git repo). It solved all inconsistencies, now I have to check some of the ideas proposed above to make it sure everything is ok.

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting distinct results for both queries. Why?

Comment: @TiagoDuque Are you saying the results of both are different? Or that duplicates are removed in both? You have the word DISTINCT in your return for both queries so isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that both notations should provide the same results, but are not.

Comment: @TiagoDuque The 2 queries are not equal. The first says "Return all N that are connect to a node without any wiki relation". The second says "Return all N that are connected to another node, ignore the wiki relation" (AKA, if there are 2 relations between N and M, where one is the wiki relation, the first query will filter it, the second will keep it)